# remove duplicated objects from javaScript array if meets certain criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array with many objects (Drugs). each object has 3 keys: "Drug1", "Drug2", and riskingRate. How can i remove duplicated objects if Drug1 and Drug2 values are same (riskingRate is not important in finding duplicats). then keep object with higher riskingRate and remove others. here is a simple array:

```
var Warfarin = [{
    "Drug1": "Warfarin",
    "Drug2": "vitamin K",
    "riskRating": "C",
}, {
    "Drug": "aspirin",
    "Drug2": "MiFEPRIStone",
    "riskRating": "C",
}, {
    "Drug1": "Warfarin",
    "Drug2": "Omacetaxine",
    "riskRating": "X",
}, {
    "Drug1": "Warfarin",
    "Drug2": "vitamin K",
    "riskRating": "X",
},{
    "Drug1": "Warfarin",
    "Drug2": "vitamin K",
    "riskRating": "A",
}]
```

in this example objects 0, 3 and 4 are duplicated and the object 3 has a higher riskingRate. (riskingRate X>D>C>B>A). how can I remove objects 0 and 4 and keep objects 1,2 and 3.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like [Array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is a good fit here.

Comment: Is it intentional that the second element has `Drug` and not `Drug1` as a key name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var weights = ["X", "D", "C", "B", "A"];

var Warfarin = [{
    "Drug1": "Warfarin",
    "Drug2": "vitamin K",
    "riskRating": "C",
}, {
    "Drug": "aspirin",
    "Drug2": "MiFEPRIStone",
    "riskRating": "C",
}, {
    "Drug1": "Warfarin",
    "Drug2": "Omacetaxine",
    "riskRating": "X",
}, {
    "Drug1": "Warfarin",
    "Drug2": "vitamin K",
    "riskRating": "X",
},{
    "Drug1": "Warfarin",
    "Drug2": "vitamin K",
    "riskRating": "A",
}];

var response = Warfarin.sort((v1, v2) => (weights.indexOf(v1.riskRating) - weights.indexOf(v2.riskRating)))
.reduce((a, c)=>{
    if(!a.some(v => (v.Drug1 == c.Drug1 && v.Drug2 == c.Drug2))){
        a.push(c);
    }
    return a;
}, []);

console.log(response);
```

What this does is to first sort the array based on the objects' `riskRating` so the higher risk objects will be at the start, then just reduce the array and don't include the duplicates in the resulting array.

Comment: Hi. thanks for your help. console: ReferenceError: weights is not defined

Comment: @johnsadeghi You're missing the `weights` variable that I've included at the start of my snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution without sorting, but with an ES6 `Map`, which would make it run in *O(n)* time instead of *O(nlogn)*:

```js
const Warfarin = [{"Drug1": "Warfarin","Drug2": "vitamin K","riskRating": "C",}, {"Drug": "aspirin","Drug2": "MiFEPRIStone","riskRating": "C",}, {"Drug1": "Warfarin","Drug2": "Omacetaxine","riskRating": "X",},{"Drug1": "Warfarin","Drug2": "vitamin K","riskRating": "X",},{"Drug1": "Warfarin","Drug2": "vitamin K","riskRating": "A",}];

const result = Array.from(Warfarin.reduce ( (acc, obj) => {
    const key = JSON.stringify([obj.Drug1,obj.Drug2]);
    return !acc.has(key) || acc.get(key).riskRating < obj.riskRating
        ? acc.set(key, obj) : acc; 
}, new Map).values());

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why `JSON.stringify([obj.Drug1,obj.Drug2])` as the key, and not just `[obj.Drug1,obj.Drug2]`, since Maps don't require keys to be strings?

Comment: Because if you pass a new array as key, it will *always* be considered different (comparison will be by reference).